# Latex Table in Wordpress

Tags: tables, columns, cell, web, rows

I want to display a Latex table on wordpress page. I am using following code for this, but the code is showing one empty cell of the left hand side column at the end of/bottom,

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
\hline
 2 & 6 \\ 
\hline 
3 & 3 \\ 
\hline 
 & 1 \\ 
\hline
\end{ltabular}
```

the table. [image]

what is wrong in this code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: wordpress will be using mathjax not tex so it's off topic here but you have `\end{ltabular}` (with `l`)  which does not match `\begin{tabular}`

Comment: Welcome to TSE! If you want to use actual LaTeX in WordPress, you can use the QuickLaTeX plugin, which uses a complete LaTeX installation on a server. It renders your LaTeX code and pipes it back into your WordPress page. See http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/ for details. I use this plugin extensively on my WordPress blog.

Comment: Thnak you for your help.

Comment: Is QuickLaTeX included as part of TeX Live Utility under some other name?